# Dynamic block cache doesn't render

Tags: 8, caching

I have a menu that renders different items based on the entity association of the node being rendered.

I've been trying many difference combinations of cache configurations for my custom block:

```
        return [
            '#theme'      => 'my_custom_menu',
            '#menu_items' => $menu,
            '#cache'      => [
                'keys'     => ['custom_menu', $node_id],
                'contexts' => ['route.name'],
            ],
        ];
```

This will work once when i flush the cache. But navigating to a different page, with a different menu association returns nothing in the block html. I've had this sporadically happen with local, but more consistently happen on Pantheon. I installed the https://pantheon.io/docs/modules#advanced-page-cache module but it doesn't fix anything.

I've tried `url.path`, i've tried just the contexts array, just the keys array. Nothing works.

Anyone come across this?

Comment: For Drupal the Pantheon link is not very helpful, the mentioned keys are tags in Drupal terms. I would debug the custom block plugin locally before deploying to your production environment.

Comment: @4k4 Locally, the block works fine

Comment: I don't believe that, at least not the version you've shown. You need cache tags instead of keys and a different context. `route.name` is the same for all nodes. Try the entire `route` or `url.path` you've already mentioned.

Comment: @4k4 Tags are used to refresh cache, not store cache - it shouldn't impact the cache lookup. You theoretically should only need a context, such as url.path, but as I've said, that has not worked and there's no explanation as to why. If you have a proposed structure feel free to write an answer and i'll test it out. How do you define the entire route? And why is that different than url.path?